# ¿Cómo leer los elementos de un archivo XML con JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, xml

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo 
**XML** usando JavaScript pero no puedo acceder a los elementos mas internos del **entry**

- Puede leer hasta el segundo nivel que seria **entry > updated** pero a los elementos mas internos no lo puedo leer.
  mi intensión es recorrer con un for y obtener todos los datos uno por uno ya que existen varios **entry**
  aldunjo mi xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xml:base="datas.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2005/04/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <id>
    </id>
    <title type="text">
        Interfaz_lista_de_clientes
    </title>
    <updated>
        2018-10-02T21:50:22Z
    </updated>
    <link href="Interfaz_lista_de_clientes" rel="self" title="Interfaz_lista_de_clientes"/>
    <entry m:etag="etasrtfsdahfhgd">
        <id> 
        </id>
        <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="Interfaz_lista_de_clientes">
        </category>
        <title>
        </title>
        <updated>
            2018-10-02T21:50:22Z
        </updated>
        <author>
            <name>
            </name>
        </author>
        <content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:no>
                    CL0989234
                </d:no>
                <d:name>
                    CLIENTE VARIOS
                </d:name>
                <d:search_name>
                    CLIENTE VARIOS
                </d:search_name>
                <d:address>
                    AV PRIMAVERA 2160 SURCO
                </d:address>
                <d:city>
                </d:city>
                <d:territory_code>
                </d:territory_code>
                <d:country_region_code>
                    PE
                </d:country_region_code>
                <d:blocked xml:space="preserve">
                </d:blocked>
                <d:vat_registration_no>
                    00000000000
                </d:vat_registration_no>
                <d:county>
                </d:county>
                <d:e_mail>
                    EMAIL.ADMIN@GMAIL.COM
                </d:e_mail>
                <d:inactivo m:type="Edm.Boolean">
                    false
                </d:inactivo>
                <d:school_no>
                </d:school_no>
                <d:school_name>
                </d:school_name>
                <d:etag>
                    23;EkHJKHA7/0MAZXVXCBXCBCVBAAA=9;987934909948;
                </d:etag>
            </m:properties>
        </content>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Quiero obtener uno por uno los datos 
                    **CL0989234
                ,
                    CLIENTE VARIOS
                ...** ... y los restos igual para luego insertarlos a la base de datos.

Este es mi código de JavaScript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Leer XML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="contenido">
    <h1>Datos Obtenidas de XML</h1>
        <div class="cuarta"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("archivo.xml",{},function(xml){ 
      $('entry',xml).each(function() { 
        codigo = $(this).find('content').text(); 
        datos = crearNoticiaHtml(codigo);
        $(".cuarta").append(datos);
      });
    }); 
  }); 
  function crearNoticiaHtml(codigo){ 
  noticiaHTML = " "; 
    noticiaHTML +=  codigo +  "<br>"; 
    return noticiaHTML;
  } 
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo es simplemente utilizar el parseador de XML de jQuery (veo que utilizas jQuery en tu código, así que no necesitarías importar nada adicional en tu página), y una vez convertido a JSON trabajar con ese objeto que es muy sencillo desde javascript.

```
var jsonData = $.parseXML(xml);
```

Toda la documentación la puedes encontrar en https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Un saludo!

Comment: por favor añade un ejemplo mínimo del parseo de datos que mencionas, eso mejorará la respuestas y será mejor recibida

Answer (score 0):

Bueno encontre una forma de como leer el archivo de forma directa, no se si es la forma correcta pero el objetivo era obtener los datos que se encuentran dentro de **m:properties** y los esta obteniendo  adjunto la URL de CodePen para ver mejor con todo el funcionamiento.

https://codepen.io/rojasrca/project/editor/DNKqGp